# react-boilerplate Error: Can't resolve '../xlsx' in '/Users/react-boilerplate/node_modules/xlsx-style'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-boilerplate

I am using react-boilerplate when I do run *npm install* I see these errors

```js
    Building the Webpack DLL...
Hash: 7f68501fbcd6b8f05530
Version: webpack 4.12.0
Time: 3566ms
Built at: 08/05/2018 6:10:17 PM
                      Asset      Size                Chunks                    Chunk Names
reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js  4.81 MiB  reactBoilerplateDeps  [emitted]  [big]  reactBoilerplateDeps
chunk {reactBoilerplateDeps} reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js (reactBoilerplateDeps) 4.15 MiB [entry] [rendered]

WARNING in ./node_modules/xlsx-style/ods.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../xlsx' in '/Users/mehrnooshhajkhalil/react-boilerplate/node_modules/xlsx-style'
 @ ./node_modules/xlsx-style/ods.js
 @ ./node_modules/xlsx-style/xlsx.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-excel-export/lib/excel.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-excel-export/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

ERROR in ./node_modules/xlsx-style/dist/cpexcel.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './cptable' in '/Users/mehrnooshhajkhalil/react-boilerplate/node_modules/xlsx-style/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/xlsx-style/dist/cpexcel.js 807:16-41
 @ ./node_modules/xlsx-style/xlsx.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-excel-export/lib/excel.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-excel-export/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

ERROR in ./node_modules/xlsx-style/xlsx.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/mehrnooshhajkhalil/react-boilerplate/node_modules/xlsx-style'
 @ ./node_modules/xlsx-style/xlsx.js 1204:27-40 1340:8-24
 @ ./node_modules/node-excel-export/lib/excel.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-excel-export/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

ERROR in ./node_modules/xlsx-style/ods.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/mehrnooshhajkhalil/react-boilerplate/node_modules/xlsx-style'
 @ ./node_modules/xlsx-style/ods.js 58:8-24
 @ ./node_modules/xlsx-style/xlsx.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-excel-export/lib/excel.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-excel-export/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps

ERROR in ./node_modules/xlsx-style/ods.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'xlsx' in '/Users/mehrnooshhajkhalil/react-boilerplate/node_modules/xlsx-style'
 @ ./node_modules/xlsx-style/ods.js 13:21-41
 @ ./node_modules/xlsx-style/xlsx.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-excel-export/lib/excel.js
 @ ./node_modules/node-excel-export/index.js
 @ dll reactBoilerplateDeps
removed 1 package and audited 53190 packages in 30.134s
```

I did also try

rm -rf node-modules 
npm clean cache --force
npm install

But none of them did not solve my problem

Node version : v10.8.0
npm version : 6.2.0

Comment: post the piece of code,  that imports the module.

Comment: and btw, it is npm clean cache.

Comment: The import statement that imports that module, in your code.

Comment: I am using react-boilerplate https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate after clone the project I do just npm install and this errors comes up.

Comment: So it is a problem with xlsx, go to the library and open an issue on their repository.

Answer (score 8):

I downloaded xlsx module using `yarn add xlsx --save` and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've read tons of related topics and tried everything. But in my case this helped:
In Webpack config in `externals` replace `{ "../xlsx.js": "var _XLSX" }` with `{ "../xlsx": "var _XLSX" }`

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in this issue like 1 week, The problem is when you want to use any package that are using export excel, they are using fs is short for file system. A browser doesn't have any.

Therefore, it is almost impossible export an excel file from reactboilerplate in front end, I did handle it by using  node-excel-export then write an API for that like this:

```js
export const exportIssues = (req, res) => {



  const styles = {
    headerDark: {
      fill: {
        fgColor: {
          rgb: 'FF000000'
        }
      },
      font: {
        color: {
          rgb: 'FFFFFFFF'
        },
        sz: 14,
        bold: true,
        underline: true
      }
    }
  };

//Here you specify the export structure
  const issueSpecification = {
    HousingManager: { // <- the key should match the actual data key
      displayName: 'Housing manager', // <- Here you specify the column header
      headerStyle: styles.headerDark, // <- Header style
      width: 120 // <- width in pixels
    },
    CompanyName: { // <- the key should match the actual data key
      displayName: 'Company name', // <- Here you specify the column header
      headerStyle: styles.headerDark, // <- Header style
      width: 120 // <- width in pixels
    },
    HousingManagerEmail: { // <- the key should match the actual data key
      displayName: 'Housing manager email', // <- Here you specify the column header
      headerStyle: styles.headerDark, // <- Header style
      width: 120 // <- width in pixels
    }
  }




  const issueData = [
    {HousingManager:'sss', CompanyName: 'xxx' ,  HousingManagerEmail:'xx@x.com'},
    {HousingManager:'sss', CompanyName: 'xxx' ,  HousingManagerEmail:'xx@x.com'},      
  ]

  const report = excel.buildExport(
    [ // <- Notice that this is an array. Pass multiple sheets to create multi sheet report
      {
        name: 'Issues', // <- Specify sheet name (optional)
        specification: issueSpecification, // <- Report specification
        data: issueData // <-- Report data
      }
    ]
  );

// You can then return this straight
  res.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=report.xlsx");
  res.set("Content-type", "application/vnd.ms-excel")
  res.attachment('report.xlsx'); // This is sails.js specific (in general you need to set headers)
  return res.send(report);


};
```

Then call this function in frontend:

```
 exportIssues = (e) =>{

    axios.get('APIURL',{
      responseType: 'blob',
    })
    .then((response) => {
      download(response.data, "Issues.xlsx", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    })
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solutions.

Please replace the following code in ods.js

```
if(typeof XLSX !== 'undefined') return XLSX.utils;
if(typeof module !== "undefined" && typeof require !== 'undefined') 
{
try 
{ 
    return require('./' + 'xlsx').utils; 
} 
catch(e) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
         return require('./' + 'xlsx').utils; 
    } 
    catch(ee) 
    { 
        return require('./xlsx').utils; 
    } 
 }
 throw new Error("Cannot find XLSX utils"); 
};
```